# XML parsing failed in SELECT query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am running the `SELECT query` from the Oracle SQL developer IDE on my RHEL box as below

```
SELECT count(*) 
From xyz 
WHERE xmltype(xyz.xmlColumn).existsNode('//name=""') = 1;
```

Above query works fine if I execute for single record. But when I execute it for the whole table it fails with the error:

```
ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
LPX-00210: expected '<' instead of 'C'
Error at line 1
ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 272
ORA-06512: at line 1
31011. 00000 -  "XML parsing failed"
*Cause:    XML parser returned an error while trying to parse the document.
*Action:   Check if the document to be parsed is valid.
```

Any pointers on above will help me.

Comment: One of your XML documents isn't XML.  You'll have to find the relevant value and fix it.

Comment: Thanks jonearles for you input. 
But still I am not able to figure it out where is the issue. The table has multiple columns. The column which is their in Where clause is of type CLOB which has XML data always.
So you want to say the XML column doesn't contain XML at some place and due to this query is failing.

Comment: 1 more thing is that this query runs fine if if I remove count as below:
`code`
SELECT *
From xyz 
WHERE xmltype(xyz.xmlColumn).existsNode('//name=""') = 1;
`code`
It encounters error only when I want to get count(*)

Comment: If your IDE only receives N rows at a time, then `select *` may appear to work better than `select count(*)`, but only because it hasn't retrieved all the records yet.  Try to find a single value that causes the error, you'll probably see something wrong with the XML.  Finding that one value can be difficult, because it's difficult to know the exact order of SQL processing.

Comment: hey Thanks for the explaination. Is their any other way to get those node counts using like operator?

Comment: It depends on your XML.  But in general, trying to parse XML with anything other than a full XML parser is asking for trouble.  Depending on what is making the XML invalid, it might be easier to fix the problem before converting it to an XMLType.  It all depends on what exactly was wrong with the XML, and if it is consistently wrong.  But you really shouldn't need to do this.  A huge benefit of XML is that it's well defined, and you should not have to mess around with it like this.  Maybe you need to push back and tell someone "this is not XML, it's useless text that kinda looks like XML."

Comment: This is the root cause why I am not XML parsing is failing.

Answer (score 1):

include /text in your xpath. like
select (COLUM_NAME).extract('//parentNode/chileNode/text()').getStringVal() as Colum_Name from TableName where UUID='Value'

Answer (score 0):

Oracle is complaining that "xyz.xmlColumn" is not a valid xml column or type. It expects `<element>....</element>` format

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is what is stored in your CLOB is not an XML document as it is missing a root node. Since you are scanning the whole document in your extract you could just wrap it in an element to ensure you have 1 and only 1 root, at which point your XMLTYPE cast would work.

SELECT
  XMLTYPE(''||clob_field||'').EXTRACT('//se/text()').getStringVal()
FROM tablename